# AngularJS - Do I need lots of API's?

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering if I will be needing a lot of API's for my angular application. This is a broad statement so let me explain a few things.

Lets say that on my page I have three selects (dropdown lists).

Fruits, Vegetables, Produce

They all have their own data,

Fruits (ID, Name, Importer Order Number, Importer Name).

Vegetables (ID, Name, Distributer ID).

Produce (ID, Name, Manufacturer Name).

So if I want to populate each of these select statements, will i have to make 3 seprate API calls? Or should I be making 1 API call returning each of these? Is it possible to make 1 API call to return all this data?

If so does anyone have a simple example?

I want to know whats best practice...

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need us to tell you how your API should work?  If you need 3 separate calls.  If you would rather send the payload back in a single call, then make 1 call.

Comment: I don't need 3 separate calls, can send all of it in 1 payload just asking whats best practice.

Comment: In this case, I don't think there's a "best" practice.  If the 3 calls can be used separately, then make it 3 calls and use them when you need them.  Otherwise it's best to reduce the number of requests and return everything at once.  But "best" for me is not necessarily "best" for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is depend on what you want to achieve, if you want a full dynamic Ajax application the answer is Yes.

Referring back to your question and scenario, if the data on the HTML element required dynamic change while attending the application then you need a separate call for each element. If the data on the HTML element doesn't require dynamic change then you can put your data into single Master Model and bind the sub object of the Master Model for the required HTML element.

As example, a single Select HTML element wont required a dynamic change, but a component of Autocomplete Select might require a independent call due to large database call and filtering process on back-end.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on your backend script. It does not matter if you are using Angularjs, jQuery or plain XHR.

For example, I often use PHP. When I want to reduce the total number of API calls, I write my PHP script such that it returns a single JSON object that contains multiple 'columns' of data.

Comment: Using C#.Net web API's. Basically what i am asking is to know if I should be bundling up all this data and sending that back to the front end or should i be making 3 seprate api calls.

Comment: C# and .Net are not my specialty, but I think generally reducing the number of API calls is often more efficient, if your backend scripting is also in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a framework that enables you to create rich client applications for web browsers.

When you make a request to a server from a modern framework such as Angular, you are typically doing one of two things:

1. Requesting static resources such as html templates (partials), images, css, js, etc.
2. Requesting data, usually prepared as a REST request, and typically returning a string that  is in JSON or XML format.  This is no different from a typical AJAX request made by most common web applications today.  Angular does provide a service for obtaining an HTTP client, but it's not proprietary by any means.

Your question refers to the design of your REST API, and has nothing to do with Angular the framework.

With that said, there are plenty tutorials on REST best practices.  And here is an article on [what to avoid](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/08/13/api-anti-patterns-how-to-avoid-common-rest-mistakes/) when designing REST services.